# select data from two tables, return data and get product name from item id

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$transactionOutput = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE emailaddress='$email'");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($productCount > 0) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $item_id = $row["item_id"];
    $quantity = $row["quantity"];
    $size = $row["size"];
    $price = $row["price"]; 

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id'");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    }

    $transactionOutput .= "<tr>";
    $transactionOutput .= "<td align='center'>" .$product_name. "</td>";
    $transactionOutput .= "<td align='center'>" .$quantity. "</td>";    
    $transactionOutput .= "<td align='center'>" .$size. "</td>";
    $transactionOutput .= "<td align='center'>" .$price. "</td>";
    $transactionOutput .= "</tr>";
}

    } else {
$transaction_list = "You have made no transactions yet";
}


?>
```

I'm trying to access data from two different tables and then return the product name of each item by matching the id in the product table with the item_id returned from the transactions table. This does output the correct information however it only shows the first transaction and no others, i know this is also probably horribly programmed too

Comment: did u run those sql manually to see if u can understand why that s happening?

Comment: Go read up on LEFT JOINs. Furthermore, `$email` and `$item_id` are not sourced (I hope you're not extracting them from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, or something like that). Next issue is that your query parameters aren't sanitized, making you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. And finally, use PDO, as the mysql family of functions should be considered deprecated.

Comment: the $email value is from the user session i have and the $item_id is from the transactions table in the database

Comment: Your query is highly insecure. Read about SQL Injection.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this is only for a university project so it won't be taken into consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using the same variable `$sql` to store the resultsets from both the queries. So what might be happening here is this:

1. the transaction query runs and the resultset is stored in $sql
2. first record is read from the transaction resultset
3. for the first transaction record, the product query runs and the resultset is stored again in $sql
4. the output is stored into $transactionOutput
5. next record is read from the transaction resultset

AND the step 5 is the problem because the original transaction resultset - `$sql` - was overwritten by the product resultset.

Try using another variable for the product query:

```
$rsProduct = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id'");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($rsProduct);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsProduct)) {
    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
}
```

Hope the above makes sense!

**EDIT**: as an additional suggestion, you may like to try using JOIN queries to retrieve both transaction and product in the same query. Here:

```
SELECT `t`.*, `p`.`product_name`
FROM `transactions` `t`
LEFT JOIN `products` `p` ON `t`.`item_id` = `p`.`id`
WHERE `t`.`emailaddress` = '$email';
```

Just loop the resultset and you are done!

Comment: by the way, don't forget to sanitize your query inputs. Read on mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$transactionOutput = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE emailaddress='$email'");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($productCount > 0) {

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $item_id = $row["item_id"];
    $quantity = $row["quantity"];
    $size = $row["size"];
    $price = $row["price"]; 

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id'");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);

   #I suggest you use a different variable (i.e. not $row) here;
    #at this point $row from the first while is still in scope
    #and clobbering it may be causing the problem you see with
    #only the first transaction showing.        
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
     #If you only need the first product_name, then you don't need the loop, just
     #$row2=mysql_fetch_arrqy($sql);
     #$product_name = $row2["product_name"];

    $product_name = $row["product_name"];
    }

    $transactionOutput .= "<tr>";
    $transactionOutput .= "<td align='center'>" .$product_name. "</td>";
    $transactionOutput .= "<td align='center'>" .$quantity. "</td>";    
    $transactionOutput .= "<td align='center'>" .$size. "</td>";
    $transactionOutput .= "<td align='center'>" .$price. "</td>";
    $transactionOutput .= "</tr>";
}

    } else {
$transaction_list = "You have made no transactions yet";
}


?>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this did work however i decided to use the left join query from below!

Comment: Excellent, I also agree the joined query is the way to go.